# Creating vertical multi level menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a verical menuBar with some submenus.
This is what I have tried.

```
<div  class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
   <li><a href="#">aaa</a>
   <ul>
   <li><a href="#">xxxxxxx</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">yyyyyyyy</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">cccccc</a></li>
   </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">bbb</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">ccc</a></li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ejt1xznu/

But,when I click on main menu sub menus are not displaying properly.What I did wrong?Can anyone help me?
Otherwise is there any way to do it using jquery or angular properly?

Comment: how is this even remotely java related? this is pure css. there are tons of "free to use" menu templates online, why don't use one of them, or look at their code?

Comment: you can use li > ul absolute like : `.nav-tabs > li ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
}` and set according to you demo : https://jsfiddle.net/ejt1xznu/1/

Comment: my doubt is ,why sub menus are hiding immedietly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mostly each `tag` in HTML have some `default styling`, same here `ul` tag has a default styling of `padding-left:40px;`. Once you reset that to `padding-left:0px;` it align remaining links properly.

**Default ul styling,**

```
ul{
display: block;
list-style-type: disc;
margin-top: 1em;
margin-bottom: 1 em;
margin-left: 0;
margin-right: 0;
padding-left: 40px;
}
```

```css
ul{
  padding:0;
}
ul ul>li {
  display:none;
}
ul li:active li{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div  class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
   <li><a href="#">aaa</a>
   <ul>
   <li><a href="#">xxxxxxx</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">yyyyyyyy</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">cccccc</a></li>
   </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">bbb</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">ccc</a></li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you.But why submenus are hiding immedietly even parent menu is activated.

Comment: Instead of ul li:active li use ul li:hover li.

Comment: active pseudo class applies it's styling when mouse press-down on selected element and set's styling back to default when mouse-release. So to select below links user have to click and drag below to select remaining links, which is not possible. So as links are aligned vertically hover should work.

Comment: If you want to do that using jQuery then use this jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/q2pskhcb/

Comment: I tried to remove `active` class of siblings when a `li` is clicked.But its not working.pls check my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/q2pskhcb/1/

Comment: That's not needed, condition is already included to check that.

Answer (score 0):

You are showing the submenu on :active. :active  state will be lost as soon as you release the menu click. That is why it is getting hide immediately. If you use :hover pseudo class, your issue can be fixed.

```
ul li:hover li{
  display:block;
}
```